# Como cambiar caracteres de label

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo el ahorcado y cada vez que el jugador acierte una letratiene que cambiar la letra por la raya pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo con un label, solo se podría hacer en un textbox?

Gracias de antemano!

```
 For i = 0 To palabraAAcertar.Length - 1
      If tbEscribirLetra.Text = palabraAAcertar(i) Then
        'reemplazar caracter
      End If
  Next
```

Comment: En principio puedes hacerlo perfectamente con un Label. ¿Qué problema te has encontrado? ¿Cómo has intentado hacerlo? Si pones el código que has intentado es más fácil que la gente pueda encontrar el problema y ayudarte.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva No encuentro la manera de reemplazar el caracter del label, lo he intentado haciendo un substring, replace y tocharArray pero no hay manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo utilizando el método `Substring`, como comentas:

```
For i = 0 To _palabraAAcertar.Length - 1
    If tbEscribirLetra.Text = _palabraAAcertar(i) Then
        labelResultado.Text =
            labelResultado.Text.Substring(0, i) &
            _palabraAAcertar(i) &
            labelResultado.Text.Substring(i + 1)
    End If
Next
```

El resultado es la concatenación del texto de los `i` caracteres primeros, el nuevo carácter que reemplazará a la raya y los caracteres siguientes al índice `i`.

También podrías utilizar un objeto `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder(labelResultado.Text)
For i = 0 To _palabraAAcertar.Length - 1
    If tbEscribirLetra.Text = _palabraAAcertar(i) Then
        sb(i) = tbEscribirLetra.Text
    End If
Next
labelResultado.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Creas un objeto `StringBuilder` con el texto inicial, reemplazas los caracteres de los índices indicados y generas la cadena resultante con el método `ToString`.